# Sumas en reportes Qweb odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo

estoy aplicando esta suma en mis reportes

```
<span t-esc="sum(line.quantity for line in o.invoice_line_ids)"/>
```

que lo que hace es suma el campo quantity que es resultante de un for...
como puedo agregarle una condicionante a esta suma? por ejemplo.. Sumar solo cuando la cantidad es mayor a 3... tengo que hacer varias variaciones de esto pero no manejo Odoo, es mi segundo dia con esta herramienta.

Comment: No he usado  Odoo pero siguiendo la sintaxis general de un generador por compresión en Python sería `sum(line.quantity for line in o.invoice_line_ids if line.quantity > 3)`...

Comment: Genial.. donde puedo documentarme mas sobre "generador por compresión en Python"?

Comment: El término correcto realmente es [expresiones generadoras](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), pero la sintaxis es básicamente la misma que usan las listas por compresión, [PEP-202](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/)

Comment: Si has logrado resolver el problema, sería bueno que lo compartieras publicando una respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

lo que te ha escrito  @FJSevilla no esta mal ,pero debes acostumbrarte a trabajar en los reportes odoo QWEB para este caso tenia que aplica asi:

```
<t t-set="test_variable" t-value="sum(line.quantity for line in o.invoice_line_ids)"/>

  <t t-if="test_variable >3">
        <span t-esc="test_variable"/>
   </t>
```

para mas informacion consulta aca:
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/qweb.html

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo necesitas solo sumar aquellas lineas donde la cantidad es mayor a 3. puedes usar

1. Como t-esc permite python dentro de él, puedes agregar la condición como si estuvieras haciendo una lista de comprensión.

```
<span t-esc="sum(line.quantity for line in o.invoice_line_ids if line.quantity > 3)"/>
```

2. también dentro de los reportes qweb tienes varias erramientas aparte de t-esc, puedes valerte de t-value, t-set, t-foreach y t-if.

```
<t t-set="total" t-value="0"/>
<t t-foreach="o.invoice_line_ids" t-as="line">
    <t t-if="line.quantity == 1" t-set="total" t-value="total+line.quantity"/>
    <t t-elif="line.quantity == 2" t-set="total" t-value="total+line.quantity*2"/>
</t>

<span t-esc="total"/>
```

este ultimo es mas largo pero te puede servir si quieres agregar otras condiciones